# Why the open-ball topology functor from $\boldsymbol{Met_c}$ to $\boldsymbol{Top_m}$ is not an isomorphism? Are they isomorphic at all?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, category-theory, metrizability

Let $\boldsymbol{Met_c}$ denote the category of metric spaces whose morphisms are all continous maps. And let $\boldsymbol{Top_m}$ denote the category of metrizable topological spaces whose morphisms are all continous maps. According to the book Abstract and Concrete Categories (The Joy of Cats), the functor from $\boldsymbol{Met_c}$ to $\boldsymbol{Top_m}$ that associate with each metric space its induced topological space is an equivalence but not an isomorphism. Why it is not an isomorphism? Are they isomorphic at all?

Comment: Are you asking why the open ball topology functor $Met_c\to Top_m$ is an equivalence but not an iso or are you asking how to show that there is no iso at all?

Comment: Good point. I will edit the question.

Comment: I have edited the question. The claim of the book is actually about that specific functor. Why it is not an isomorphism?

Comment: But anyway, are they isomorphic at all?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `\boldsymbol` and not `\mathbf`?

Comment: Perhaps mathbf is the right choice here (at least on Met and Top), but I usually use boldsymbol because I think mathbf don't have italic. If it have, I think I am confusing it with another command.

Comment: Yes, mathbf don't have italic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/bold-italic-vectors

Comment: I have confirmed that the book don't use italic on these notations, so I should have used mathbf. But I actually used boldsymbol because I usually use bold letrers for vectos, and I want vectors denoted by bold italic letters, and I haven't realized that the notation for categories don't have itallic. I am starting to learn category theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different metrics on the same set can yield identical topologies (consider scaling a given metric). So the functor in question is not injective.

Comment: Are these categories isomorphic at all?

Comment: @JoãoJúnior If I recall correctly, we can get an isomorphism under strong set-theoretic assumptions (like [$V=L$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility)), but no "reasonable" isomorphism exists. Which sort of phenomenon is part of the motivation for equivalence as the "right" notion of sameness.

Comment: Really what you need to get an isomorphism is global choice.  See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223331/two-categories-mod-r-and-mod-m-nr/2223347#2223347) for some discussion.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, exactly. (I brought up V=L to avoid set vs. class annoyances, but I probably should have just said what I meant.)