Why should the categories with 1 and 2 elements be considered "the same"?
In my course notes about the basics of category theory, the following is said. This is why a candidate definition of an equivalence of categories is not a good choice.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category with one object, $\star$ and hence one morphism $1_\star$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the category with two objects, $X$ and $Y$, and four morphisms: $1_X$, $1_Y$, $f:X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$. Then clearly $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms, so $D$ can be thought of as "two copies of $\star$". So we would like to consider $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ to be equivalent.
However, there are no functors $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and $G: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ such that $FG = 1_\mathcal{D}$ and $GF = 1_\mathcal{D}$.


I am stuck on the part that says "So we would like to consider $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ to be equivalent. I also understand that they are in fact equivalent when considering the actual definition of equivalent categories. But why would we "want" these to be equivalent when they are, in my opinion, so fundamentally different? One has one object and the other has two?
In a way, I am kind of asking why we choose this definition of equivalence of categories and not the "naive" definition of requiring $FG = 1$ and $GF = 1$.
Any help in understanding the broad idea behind this is appreciated! Thanks!

@Randall Wikipedia also proposes this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories#Examples

@Randall I've actually come across this post now. Should have done a little more research first. I'll close this question as it is more or less a copy of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432782/how-different-can-equivalent-categories-be

The language of categories does not mention equality of objects, only isomorphism. $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent from the point of view of category theory. See principle of equivalence.

@NaïmFavier Yes, the key part in understanding why "different" categories can be considered equivalent, is that equivalent categories can be thought of as "the same", up to some amount of duplicates of isomorphic objects. In hindsight, this also makes sense from a "equivalence iff fully faithful and essentially surjective" POV

In homotopy type theory, $\mathcal{D}$ is not a category, only a precategory. Its Rezk completion is isomorphic (thus equal) to $\mathcal{C}$.

@NaïmFavier Interesting! I am not familiar with homotopy type theory, only "basic" category theory. Might look into that some time!
